# How do I display an HTML file using Websphere Liberty?

Tags: html, apache, websphere-liberty, static-content

I have static HTML pages. Using the Apache server (through XAMPP) I used to put my HTML files in the `htdocs` folder and they would be accessible through the localhost URL.

I'm not sure how to do this with Websphere Liberty server. let's say I have the following HellWorld HTML example in `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HellWorld</title>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <p>HellWorld</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get this HTML page to show in the browser through Liberty?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minimum folder structure needed is the following

```
+ SampleHTMLSite.war
  - index.html
```

To create the `.war` file just zip your `index.html` file and then change the extention of the zipped folder from `.zip` to `.war`

If you are running Liberty sever in foreground through `server run` command, as soon as you put this website in Liberty's `dropins` folder (usually located here: `...\wlp\usr\servers\YourServerName\dropins`) you will get something like the following update:

```
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): 
           http://localhost:9080/SampleHTMLSite/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application SampleHTMLSite started in 0.317 seconds.
```

If you go to `http://localhost:9080/SampleHTMLSite/index.html` you should be able to see your HelloWorld HTML page.

If you get the following error:

```
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /index.html
```

Open your SampleHTMLSite.war with any unzipping program (example: [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) and be sure that the `index.html` is showing directly inside the `.war` file and not inside another folder. There is a chance that you have the following structure:

```
+ SampleHTMLSite.war
  + SampleHTMLSite
    - index.html
```

This would mean to access the `index.html` you need the following URL:

`http://localhost:9080/SampleHTMLSite/SampleHTMLSite/index.html`

In bigger project and where you need to use Java apps your folder structure might need to include other folders and files. If you are intrested to know more about this, check the following article:

[Handling Static Content in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0211_brown/brown.html)

Comment: To make things easier, you don't actually have to create the archive (zip/war), and instead you can just create the folder that's named with the ".war" suffix like "SampleHTMLSite.war"

Answer (score 6):

The simplest:

- In `dropins` folder (`\wlp\usr\servers\serverName\dropins`), create folder `myApp.war`
- put your `index.html` in the `myApp.war`

If your server is configured for polled monitoring you are done. Otherwise restart the server (if was started).
It will be available via `http://host:port/myApp/index.html`.