# Serve static files in openLiberty

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am trying to serve a static file on OpenLiberty application but haven't found a straightforward way to do so.

At first I simply put the file in the src/resources and webapp/META-INF folder but it seems that this is not enough.After a bit of research I found a few approaches which all didn't fit my needs.

For instances [0] suggested placing the file in the dropin folder. But this is a folder in the deployed app and I need the file within the source root folder at build time.
Another post [1] suggested created a custom config file but that is for WAS only.
When I started to look more broadly (JaxRS) there was even the idea to create Rest endpoint that loads the file from the classpath [2]. This idea, while being plausible, seems to complicated for what I intend to accomplish. I even found a config option (fileServingEnabled) in the official documentation [3] but the description is thin on how to properly configure it.

Is it possible to do that with plain OpenLiberty or do I have to go another way in order to achieve that?

[0] [How do I display an HTML file using Websphere Liberty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305207/how-do-i-display-an-html-file-using-websphere-liberty)

[1] https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005pgfiVCAQ/how-serve-static-html-files?language=en_US

[2] [How to serve static content with JAX-RS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642920/how-to-serve-static-content-with-jax-rs/51074375)

[3] https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.9/reference/config/webContainer.html

Comment: Static files in the root of the WAR work fine for me . This is where maven puts static content from /src/main/webapp by default for a war.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @covener I'll give it a go